# Does _printf require pre-additional space on the stack for it to work?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, assembly, x86-64

I'm working on a side project, which is a mini compiler. I'm having trouble understanding why `_printf` requires at least 16-bytes of stack space for it to work when printing one integer?

My code snippet below prints `42` as desired.

**16-byte Stack**

```
.global    _main
    _main:
    pushq    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $42, %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%rsp)
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    movl    -4(%rsp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    callq    _printf
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq

.section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:
    .asciz    "%d\n"
```

If I change the stack size below `16`, it causes a crash, say to `12`:

```
subq  $12, %rsp
...
...
addq  $12, %rsp
```

I'm compiling the assembly code as such: `gcc -o IntegerTest IntegerTest.s`

Comment: Is this for MacOS?

Comment: @MichaelPetch It's being compiled and ran on Macos.

Comment: MacOS uses the 64-bit System V ABI. It requires 16 (or 32-byte depending on parameters). It is possible that the function being called uses a an aligned instruction (aligned SIMD) with a memory location on the stack. You also need to make sure that _AL_  has the number of vector registers used to pass parameters (in this case _AL_ needs to be zero)

Comment: I suspect though that _AL_ being non zero and the fact that the stack is misaligned causes the problem. You can read about the 64-bit System V ABI here: https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks! I would've never known!